# I want to implement deep linking which other apps recognize and open my app

Tags: react-native

I have deep linked my app to scheme example://test/:id.What i want to do is to convert this to a www.someurl.com/test/:id but have no clue how to do this.
I want to make it a link that can be shared and will open the app something like https://shrts.in/JRnN.

### My url handler looks something like this i am using react-native-deep-linking

```
   componentDidMount() {

     DeepLinking.addScheme('example://');
     Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
     DeepLinking.addRoute('/test/:id', (response) => {
       // example://test/23
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Article',{id:response});
     });

     Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
       if (url) {
         Linking.openURL(url);
       }
     }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
     Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
   }

   handleUrl = ({ url }) => {
     Linking.canOpenURL(url).then((supported) => {
       if (supported) {
         DeepLinking.evaluateUrl(url);
       }
     });
   }
```

Is there room for improvement ,I am relatively new to react.All the references online are mostly outdated.I am able to open this app using adb  like this

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://test/346" com.app
```

But i want top open it from a url which i can enter in browser something like www.someurl.com/test/:id asuming i have my website hosted

## Edit

### This is my intent in manifest

```
<intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:pathPattern="/.*"></data>
           <data android:scheme="example" android:host="test" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters Here is the offical document for deeplink on android.
Sorry I don't test it for the first time!

```
<intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="test" />
</intent-filter>
```

Try add another one intent-filter .And use `"adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://test"` to open the app .It seems now you cannot open the app by input directly in the browser.But try to write a html file and add the link in an a tag,you will find the app is opened!

Comment: I have already done that but it still does not open up anything.I have read that this is an intent and you need a url that will send your app this intent or something idk

Comment: I want to make it a link that can be shared and will open the app something like https://shrts.in/JRnN

Comment: Thank you for the answer,i have already corrected and implemented that part what i really want to know is how can i open this using direct url instead to a herf to the uri.